# trying to embed to use html in jsp scriplet tag

Tags: java, html, jsp

I am retrieving a session attribute in a jsp page and I want if the session is null let it display the login button to the login screen. This is my attempt but I am having challenge of using the html in a jsp scriplet tag as shown

```
<span style="float:right; top:-10px;  position: relative; color:#000; font-size: 80%">
                 <% if(session.getAttribute("email") != null)
                    {
                                      out.println(session.getAttribute("email"));
                    }else{
            <a href="/login-admin" class="btn btn-default"style="color:#4b4f54; font-weight:bold; border:1px solid #4b4f54;">Log In</a> 
                    }
                 %>
            </span>
```

Is it possible to use html in scriplet tag of jsp

Comment: You should never ever ever ever ever use scriptlets... period! See [jstl](https://jstl.java.net/)

Comment: @LanceJava it is good for beginner's practice.... otherwise - you're absolutely right ;-)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You need to close the scriplet before adding the html code... trying changing your code to this.

```
<% if(session.getAttribute("email") != null)
{
 out.println(session.getAttribute("email"));
}else{ %>
<a href="/login-admin" class="btn btn-default"style="color:#4b4f54; font-weight:bold; border:1px solid #4b4f54;">Log In</a> 
<%} %>
```

Answer (score 1):

Just open/close scriplet  whenever necessary ... `<% if {%> htmlcode <%}>`
in your case:

```
<span style="float:right; top:-10px;  position: relative; color:#000; font-size: 80%">
                 <% if(session.getAttribute("email") != null)
                    {
                                      out.println(session.getAttribute("email"));
                    }else{%>
            <a href="/login-admin" class="btn btn-default"style="color:#4b4f54; font-weight:bold; border:1px solid #4b4f54;">Log In</a> 
 <%           }
                 %>
            </span>
```

Answer (score 1):

you can just close the jsp tag then insert the html the open the jsp tags again look at my examples.

```
<TABLE BORDER=2>
<%
for ( int i = 0; i < n; i++ ) {
    %>
    <TR>
    <TD>Number</TD>
    <TD><%= i+1 %></TD>
    </TR>
    <%
}
%>
</TABLE>
```

and :

```
<%
if ( hello ) {
    %>
    <p>This actually works?</p>
    <%
} else {
    %>
    <p>This is amazing </P>
    <%
}
%>
```

In your case like this:

```
<span style="float:right; top:-10px;  position: relative; color:#000; font-size: 80%">
             <% if(session.getAttribute("email") != null)
                {
                                  out.println(session.getAttribute("email"));
                }else{%>
        <a href="/login-admin" class="btn btn-default"style="color:#4b4f54; font-weight:bold; border:1px solid #4b4f54;">Log In</a> 
                <% }
             %>
        </span>
```